# Matlab not able to read in large file?

Tags: matlab, memory

I have a data file (6.3GB) that I'm attempting to work on in MATLAB, but I'm unable to get it to load, and I think it may be a memory issue. I've tried loading in a smaller "sample" file (39MB) and that seems to work, but my actual file won't load at all. Here's my code:

```
filename = 'C://Users/Andrew/Documents/filename.mat';
load(filename);

??? Error using ==> load
Can't read file C://Users/Andrew/Documents/filename.mat.

exist(filename);
EDU>> ans = 2
```

Well, at least the file exists. When I check the memory...

```
memory
Maximum possible array:            2046 MB (2.146e+009 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   3442 MB (3.609e+009 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:              296 MB (3.103e+008 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):             8175 MB (8.572e+009 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
```

So since I have enough RAM, do I need to increase the maximum possible array size? If so, how can I do that without adding more RAM?

System specifics: I'm running 64-bit Windows, 8GB of RAM, MATLAB Version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a). I think I can't update to a newer version since I'm on a student license.

Comment: You can not increase the Maximum possible array, unfortunately. This means that there is no way of having a single variable loaded that has more than `2046Mb` in your case. The only option that I see feasible is to load it in pieces, as you can load up to `8175Mb` of data. This is not fully true, because you need the RAM memory to run Matlab, windows, etc, but you get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

As the size might be the issue, you could try `load('fileName.mat', 'var1'); load('fileName.mat', 'var2');` etc. For this, you'll have to know the variable names though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the variable names, and my guesses for what they're named don't seem to be correct. If push comes to shove, though, I can try to track down the person who created the file and ask them.

Comment: Good news: I figured out what the variable name is. Bad news: the file is a 1x1 structure, so it looks like I can't just load parts of it at a time.

Comment: 'Using load('fileName.mat', 'a*');' will read all variables starting with the a, this way, you're probably done in 26 steps (assuming they are all starting with a-z).

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use the matfile object to load/index directly into the file instead of loading into ram.

```
doc matfile
```

But one limitation is that you can not index directly into a struct. So you would need to find a friend to convert the struct in your mat file and save it with the version option

```
save(filename, variables, '-v7.3')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can load part by part your data to do your stuff using [load part of variables from mat file](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html). You must have matlab 7.3 or newer.

Answer (score -1):

From your file path I can see you are using Windows. Matlab is only 32 bit for Windows and Linux (there is no 64 bit for these OSes **at least for older releases, please see my edit**), which means you are limited to <4GB ram total for a single application (no matter how much you have in your system), this is a 32 bit application issue so there is nothing you can do to remedy it. Interestingly the Mac version is 64 bit and you can use as much ram as you want (in my computer vision class we often used my mac to do our big video projects because windows machines would just say "out of memory")

As you can see from your memory  output you can only have ~3.4GB total for matrix storage, this is far less than the 6.3GB file. You'll also notice, you can only use ~2GB for one particular matrix (that number changes as you use more memory).

Typically when working with large files you can read the file line by line, rather than loading the entire file into memory. But since this is a `.mat` file that likely wouldn't work. If the file contains multiple variables maybe separate them each into their own individual files that are small enough to load

The take home message here is you can't read the entire file at once unless you hop onto a Mac with enough RAM. Even then the size for a single matrix is still likely less than 6.3GB

**EDIT**

Current Matlab **student** versions can be purchased in 64 bit for all OSes as of 2014 [see here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94005-is-the-matlab-student-version-supported-for-64-bit-operating-systems) so a newer release of Matlab **might** allow you to read the entire file at once. I should also add there has been a 64 bit version before 2014, but not for the student license

Comment: Matlab has had 64 bit versions for both Windows and Linux ever since R2006; 64 bit versions for the Mac wasn't a thing until R2009 or so. The take home message is he needs to get hold of 64-bit Matlab, not switch the entire OS.

Comment: @Setsu You are correct, If you look at my edit I forgot to mention 64 bit was not avaliable for student licenses till recently (with the exception of Mac and apparently linux in 2013)